# Bash Pipe File-Redirect Prints �

Tags: bash

I have a program that runs and I pipe the output to a file.

```
program > file.txt
```

The above command is run every half hour. One time it printed new data, followed by about a page of �, and then old data. I'm curious on why this happened, or how this happened. It's been running for ~3k times and failed this one time. Did the OS (mac) just hickup?

The program is maven and it runs some automation code (e.g. mvn clean test -Dtest=XYZ). If the maven fails then it will re-run the same command again (pmvn clean...). I am not sure how to duplicate this. Since it has happened it has been running fine.

Comment: Not so easy to tell if we have no clue what `program` is and does.

Comment: You'll have to give more information of your issue. It could be anything as currently stated.

Comment: New output followed by garbage followed by old output sounds vaguely like filesystem corruption, but with no details, this is pure speculation. Not a programming question really then.

Comment: your title says `pipe` which is the `|` char, while your sample code shows "file-redirection" with the `>` char. Please improve your title. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly not an issue with bash or your OS, but with the program you're running. The � symbol means that your program is outputting something that doesn't consist of printable characters. Either it's outputting binary data rather than text (whether by design or otherwise), or an error's occurring that causes its textual output to be garbled.